# Summing over indices

Tags: summation

Suppose I have a simple equation with indices, like the one shown in the image. How can I use Mathematica to implement it? I am aware of summing when a specific variable changes value of some range, but the stated problem is different. Here the index references to a location in a list, and the value in that list can be many things.

[image]

Comment: do you mean something like: Sum[((n[[j]] - 1) Nmax)/n[[j]], {j, i, Nmax}], where n is a list with at least Nmax elements?

Comment: Yes. That is right.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer to the original post.

Comment: What about `Nmax Total[1 - 1/n]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting comment into an answer:

```
Sum[((n[[j]] - 1) Nmax)/n[[j]], {j, i, Nmax}]
```

, where n is a list with at least Nmax elements.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is you list, more elegant than `Sum`:

```
Total[1 - 1 / n] Length[n]
```